# nextflow: command not found

Tags: linux, nextflow

I am trying to use nextflow to run a pipeline, however when I run it it keeps saying `nextflow: command not found`. I have installed nextflow (I followed this tutorial https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/getstarted.html)

Do I need to add the path to nextflow in the config file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to move `nextflow` in a directory into $your PATH or use `./nextflow` (provide it has been downloaded in the your current path)

Comment: Thank you! Its been driving me crazy, indeed it was the latter